# Blur filter in C results in black-ish image

Tags: c, pixel, cs50

I'm working on CS50 week 4 : blur filter picture. I have to implement a box blur algorithm that works by taking each pixel and, for each color value, giving it a new value by averaging the color values of neighboring pixels. But the output is always a black-ish picture and I can't figure out why.

Can someone give me a hint of where I am wrong? Thank you!

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            BYTE red_sum = 0;
            BYTE green_sum = 0;
            BYTE blue_sum = 0;
            float pixel_count = 0.0;

            // Row above
            if (i > 0)
            {
                red_sum += copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
                green_sum += copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum += copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
                pixel_count++;
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    red_sum += copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                    green_sum += copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue_sum += copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                    pixel_count++;
                }
                if (j < (width - 1))
                {
                    red_sum += copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                    green_sum += copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue_sum += copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                    pixel_count++;
                }
            }

            // Row underneath
            if (i < (height - 1))
            {
                red_sum += copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
                green_sum += copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum += copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;
                pixel_count++;
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    red_sum += copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                    green_sum += copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue_sum += copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                    pixel_count++;
                }
                if (j < (width - 1))
                {
                    red_sum += copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                    green_sum += copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue_sum += copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                    pixel_count++;
                }
            }

            // Same row
            red_sum += copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            pixel_count++;
            if (j > 0)
            {
                red_sum += copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum += copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum += copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                pixel_count++;
            }
            if (j < (width - 1))
            {
                red_sum += copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed;
                green_sum += copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue_sum += copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                pixel_count++;
            }

            // Find average
            BYTE average_red = round(red_sum / pixel_count);
            BYTE average_green = round(green_sum / pixel_count);
            BYTE average_blue = round(blue_sum / pixel_count);

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = average_red;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average_green;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average_blue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what is the maximum value that `BYTE red_sum` can hold? What is the maximum sum of 9 pixels' values? Along with `float pixel_count = 0.0;` you have the types the wrong way round. The result is that typical colour component cannot be > 255 / 9, which is 28, blackish.

Comment: No point in invoking `round()` since there's no floating point